# Linq To Entities Result In ViewBag Throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**If you read this question, be aware that debugger may point a to different line than the one where the actual error is, check my answer.**

I have the following in my controller:

```
(1) ViewBag.AppointmentSlot = context.AppointmentSlots.Where(s => s.ID == id).Single();
```

And in my view, I do as follows:

```
(2) @ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.Day.Add(ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.StartTime).ToString()
```

And it throws the following exception on the line above (2):

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

Help is appreciated.

---

Edit:

`AppointmentSlot.Day` is of type `DateTime`

`AppointmentSlot.StartTime` is of type `TimeSpan`

---

Edit 2:

I can access ViewBag properties during debug, `ViewBag.AppointmentSlot` is not `null` at the point where the exception above is thrown.

I have tried to force LINQ To Entities to eager load the AppointmentSlot with no success:

```
ViewBag.AppointmentSlot = context.AppointmentSlots.Where(s => s.ID == id).ToList().Single();
ViewBag.AppointmentSlot = context.AppointmentSlots.Where(s => s.ID == id).ToList()[0];
```

Both results in a DynamicProxy type (lazy loading).

---

Edit 3:

For those that may wonder: I do not redirect to another view from the controller action, I simply `return View()`.

---

Comment: did you debug it? What is `ViewBag.AppointmentSlot` value? If null you should check it in a `if statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.Day.Add(ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.StartTime).ToString()
</div>
<p>
  ...
</p>
--> <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentSlotID" value="@ViewBag.AppointmetnSlot.ID" />
```

Debugger displayed the wrong line. The problem was that the following had been mistyped: `value="@ViewBag.AppointmetnSlot.ID"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `ViewBag.AppointmentSlot` is not null:

```
if (ViewBag.AppointmentSlot != null) {
    @ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.Day.Add(ViewBag.AppointmentSlot.StartTime).ToString()
}
```